# Getting dots for classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span with id and classes like this:

```
<span id="foobar" class="foo bar baz"></span>
```

I would like to get the id and classes and put them in Jquery object:

```
var sd2 = $('span').attr('id');
var sd3 = $('span').attr('class');


$('span').text('#' + sd2 + '.' + sd3);

$('span').text(function (i, text) {
    return text.replace(/ /g, '');
});
```

This is a good start but the problem is the output is this:

```
#foobar.foobarbaz
```

Jquery object will give "undefined" becuase I need dots like so:

```
 #foobar.foo.bar.baz
```

How do I get those dots in there?

[Example at JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JWhr/1/)

Comment: Not sure i understand exactly what you want to do, but if you change this line to `return text.replace(/ /g, '.');` It will output #foobar.foo.bar.baz

Comment: @Tim B James I was thinking that would somehow not be good because I also put # and tagname and other things in real script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to go from

```
foo bar baz
```

to

```
foo.bar.baz
```

so rather than replacing the whitespace with nothing (essentially removing them), replace it with a dot:

```
var sd2 = $('span').attr('id');
var sd3 = $('span').attr('class').replace(/ /g, '.');


$('span').text('#' + sd2 + '.' + sd3);
```

Comment: I think this is the best way for my script, thank you very much:)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the output to be

```
#foobar.foo bar baz
```

and not without the spaces as you show it since classes are separated with a space character.

You can do a simple replace to get the .

```
sd3.replace(/\s/g,".")
```

Answer (score 1):

You needed a dot in there, like so:

```
$('span').text(function (i, text) {
    return text.replace(/ /g, '.');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('span').text(function (i, text) {
    return text.replace(/ /g, '');
});
```

To

```
$('span').text(function (i, text) {
    return text.replace(/ /g, '.');
});
```

The class list has spaces in them and you are removing them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var sd3 = $('span').attr('class').split(" ").join(".");
// Result = foo.bar.baz

$('span').text('#' + sd2 + '.' + sd3);
// Result = #foobar.foo.bar.baz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the spaces with `.` like so:

```
$('span').attr('class').replace(/ /g,'.');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8JWhr/2/

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
sd3 = sd3.split(" ").join(".") ;
```

and then use sd3. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hxLX8/1/)